# How can I turn off Wi-Fi localisation on the Pi 3 B+?

Tags: wifi, pi-3b+, locale

I have the Pi 3 B+ and wanted to know if there was any way to turn of the need for the Wi-Fi localisation as when travelling around different countries and using my Pi as an access point I have keep changing it, whereas on the old Pi 3 B there was need to include this additional step? Hopefully someone may know what needs to be changed in order to stop the Pi from checking?

Comment: "I have keep changing it" Why? Do you get an error message?

Comment: When traveling around and connect to a different country WiFi I guess some data is transferred between the access point and the WiFi usb on my Pi I have to select the WiFi country then reboot before it lets me choose a WiFi connection.

Answer (score 2):

You can simply disable the wifi-country service with:

```
rpi3+ ~$ sudo systemctl disable wifi-country.service
```

But when I enable the service again it has no effect. `systemctl status wifi-country.service` tells me `Wi-Fi is disabled because the country is not set` but WiFi is always working. Seems to be a bug but that shouldn't matter you.

Comment: Thanks Ingo I will give that a go as I just want to be able to select a WiFi connection without having to add an additional step. Thanks

Comment: I have just tried this so forgot my WiFi connection then set a random country that’s not GB. Completed command sudo systemctl disable wifi-country.service then I’m unable to select any wifi access point 

Comment: Should I remove the service so it doesn’t even start?

Comment: @Daza85 No, I wouldn't remove the service. There may be dependencies to other services. After reboot check with `systemctl status wifi-country.service`. It should be _loaded; disabled_ and _inactive (dead)_ without further messages. Seems we are on different software level. I use `Raspbian Stretch Lite` without GUI.

Answer (score 0):

This is purely speculation on my part, but the Foundation states "WiFi is disabled until wireless regulatory domain is set (Pi 3 B+ only)".

I assume this is a condition of WiFi certification.

On the Pi3 the WiFi was restricted to channels 1-11, unless a suitable wireless regulatory domain is set. This satisfied all domains, even the FCC, because these channels are permitted in all jurisdictions.

Unfortunately there is NO 5GHz band or set of channels which are universally supported, and many administrations have a number of other restrictions to minimise interference.

I would have suggested `disable wifi-country.service`, as suggested.
This effectively just runs `/usr/lib/raspberrypi-sys-mods/wifi-country` which is a simple script to check `/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf` to see if a country is specified.

I can't see anything which would actually check what country you are actually in, but as the nearest country is a 4 hour flight away I am not in a position to try.

I did try setting my country to `GB` and my WiFi (2.4GHz) works.

You problem may be simply selecting a regulatory domain which does not match the surrounding WiFi networks. The regulatory domain definitely does affect how the on-board WiFi chip operates.

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply i have been trying different things but if i was to give this to someone whom has limited knowledge i think changing the wifi country just causes issues with an additional step. So far i have found file responsible like you suggested and can see it is checking /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf. So wondered if there was anyone whom knew how to alter the file so it checks it has nothing set? Basically work in reverse?