# Raspberry Pi 3 b+ WIFI Localisation

Tags: wifi, pi-b+, pi-3b+, locale

This is the file that determines if the wifi location has been set so i wanted to know how to alter it so it checks to see if the wifi-country is not set to enable instead. Any ideas?? So basically work in reverse.

I have tried disabling the service from running that executes this file but no luck.

sudo nano /usr/lib/raspberrypi-sys-mods/wifi-country

```
#!/bin/sh

if ! /bin/grep -q '^Revision\s*:\s*[ 123][0-9a-fA-F][0-9a-fA-F][0-9a-fA-F]0[dD][0-9a-fA-F]$' /proc/cpuinfo ; then
        exit 0
fi

if /bin/grep -q "^country=[A-Z][A-Z]" /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf; then
        exit 0
fi

if [ ! -x "/usr/sbin/rfkill" ]; then
        echo "rfkill not installed"
        exit 1
fi
mkdir -p "/var/lib/systemd/rfkill"

address="$(/bin/grep -m 1 /mmc /proc/iomem | /usr/bin/cut -f1 -d-)"
if [ -z "$address" ]; then
        echo "Could not determine WiFi iomem address"
        exit 1
fi
persist_file="/var/lib/systemd/rfkill/platform-$address.mmc:wlan"

/bin/echo 1 > "$persist_file"
/usr/bin/touch /run/wifi-country-unset
/bin/echo "Wi-Fi is disabled because the country is not set"
```

Comment: You want to [disable wifi-country.service](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/83068/79866), right?

Comment: Yea I tried disabling the service but still quotes WiFi country not set even after a reboot.

Comment: Have you looked at the link? I have tested it with `Raspbian Stretch Light 2018-04-18` on `RPi 3B+` and it works. What is the difference to yours?

Comment: Yes I tried disabling the service but somehow it still won’t let me connect to a new SSID or wen I forget my home one and try to reconnect no luck.

Comment: What is the difference between your installation and [Raspbian Stretch Light 2018-04-18](https://www.raspberrypi.org/downloads/raspbian/)? Have you tried a fresh flashed `Raspbian Stretch Light 2018-04-18` for testing? What does you give the command `sudo iw dev wlan0 scan` (wlan0 resp. your wifi interface) ? Do you find your access point?